# Javascript for multiplying fields not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript

my javascript is

```
function multiplycal(){
          var values=$(".values").val();  
          var total = 0.0;

         for(var i=0;i<values;i++)
         {
            var amtfield=trim($(".price"+i).val());       
            var quantity=trim($(".quantity"+i).val());
            total= parseFloat(total)+(parseFloat(amtfield) * parseInt(quantity));

         }

         alert(total);
            $('.sum').html(formatDoll(total));
        }

     function formatDoll(number) {
        var pip = number.toFixed(2).split(".");
        return pip[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, number, i, orig) {
            return  number+ (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
        }, "") + "." + pip[1];
    }
```

and my Vf Page is

```
<apex:outputpanel>
 <apex:variable value="0" var="rowNum"/> 
      <apex:dataTable value="{!templook}" var="item" style="margin-left:60px;"  cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6"   >
 <apex:column headerValue="Quantity">
                      <apex:outputlabel Value="{!item.Quantity__c}" onblur="multiplycal();" styleclass="quantity{!rowNum}"/>
                  </apex:column>
                   <apex:column headerValue="Unit Price($)">
                     <apex:outputlabel Value="{!item.Price__c}" styleClass="price{!rowNum}" onblur="multiplycal();"/>
                  </apex:column>
  </apex:datatable>
           <input type="hidden" value="{!rowNum}" class="values" name="values"/>  
</apex:outputpanel>
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >          
                     <apex:outputLabel value="total($) :"/>
                     <apex:outputLabel value="" styleClass="sum"  style="width:78px;text-align:right;display:block;font-size:12px;color:#000000;" />
                     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

now need to multiple price*quantity. Where I'm wrong?????? Any Suggestions are also welcomed

Comment: What is currently happening?

Comment: Nothing is Displaying....

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "no conflict" call to jQuery - this is pretty much mandatory for jQuery to work on a VisualForce page, as the '$' symbol is used by both the SalesForce and jQuery codebase.
Put this at the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Then to call jQuery functions, use j$ rather than $.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript doesn't match your class names. You're looking for fields with classes of "price" and "quantity" but your Visualforce page is outputting price1, quantity1, price2, quantity2, etc . . .

Try removing the `{!rowNum}` merge fields.

Comment: then wat about my  class="values" name="values".Where should I declare this

Comment: I would expect .values to work for that. Try walking through with a debugger like Firebug or alerts to check the variables. You can use `debugger;` to insert a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your primary problem is that multiplycal() is called on blur of your apex:outputLabels.

That is a strange way to expect users to use your vf page.  According to your code a user needs to put focus on the text produced by the outputLabel and then remove that focus for multiplycal() to be called.  The multiplycal() function should probably be called on on dom ready e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  multiplycal();
});
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply....when I used the inputtext the onblur works great....but for outputlabel as you said it doesn't works.I never used the document function.can u be a bit more clear